# Change code in production without deployment - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using asp.net

In my .cs page I am setting a value for a variable [count = 12]. count is a var, which I have declared on the aspx page.

Now I have to change the vlaue of the count = 13. which should be written in the !IspostBack event in the Page_Load(). But the issue is this that it's a very small change and I can't re deploy my website for this small change.

Is their any way I can modify the code in the production site whitout re deploying it?

Comment: Having hard coded values in code pose a known risk: when you need to change them, it means you have to re-compile the code and put the updated DLL file on production. Do as Nasser suggested, put the value in the web.config file, publish the new version to production once and any future change won't require deploying anymore just changing the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a change in the server side code, you don't need to re-deploy the full application. Just replace the existing project output library (dll) with the new one. It should be in the "bin" folder of your application.

Also, if you frequently needs to change the value of a variable, consider storing it in the AppSettings section in the web.config file.

Comment: If you are using a WebApplication project, then it most probably, it should be "NameOfYourProject.dll". If you are using "WebSite" project, then it will be "NameOfTheAspxPage.aspx.<someRandomChars>.compiled. Can somebody else verify it ? I am not 100% sure. If you look into the "bin" folder, you will be able to guess.

Comment: I have these dlls.. App_Code.dll , App_Web_brefkxyq.dll, App_Web_itp2ewo3.dll , DAL.dll , System.Web.dll , App_global.asax.dll , BLL.dll , Common.dll. and similar kind of dlls. There is no dll with the project name. My prject name is ETDL. Please suggest

Comment: Do you have any dll named like "App_Web_NameOfTheAspxPage.aspx.<someRandomChars>.dll ?  (where NameOfTheAspxPage is your Aspx page)

Comment: These are the dll's releated to the App_Web name App_Web_zgerbgvc.dll, App_Web_wjisf0bj.dll , App_Web_rkmp0gs7.dll , App_Web_itp2ewo3.dll, App_Web_godoiraw.dll and App_Web_brefkxyq.dll.

Comment: Basically, as per my understanding, every aspx page in the website project, compiles into a different dll library. So, I was trying to find if you are able to locate that dll. But this doesn't look to be the case here. And as this is your production environment, I won't suggest any risks. The best would be to publish a new build. Or you can wait for somebody else' response.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases the best approach is to define this variable in Web.Config (AppSetting) and then read that value. So that upcoming changes won't need a deploy. But for the first time you need to write your code and publish it again.

---

You can also use another builder to build the only page that you want,  but the cost of the time for such a thing just for once, is more than publishing the project again.